# Multiple files with Filepicker

Tags: filepicker.io

How can I select multiple files at once with filepicker.io? I can only find examples selecting one file at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it.

If you are using the widgets, then set `data-fp-option-multiple="true"` (Note that it is the string true)

If you are using the javascript library, then set `{'multiple': true}` in the options.

Both examples in code:
http://jsfiddle.net/yQJcL/

Comment: Is there a way to select an entire folder?

Comment: I'm going to add my comment that the docs don't really make this entirely clear. I think the docs are in need of at least a basic (or complete) code example or two. For a programmer that mostly deals with jQuery the little differences can become head-scratchers.

Comment: the examples on jsfiddle don't work for me...they send an alert message immediately after one file upload